# Adding addition logic to a stored procedure

Tags: sql, case

Im working in a stored procedure where i need to update its function.

The Stored proc insert data to a table and add a 0 flag and we run a batch it will set the flag to 1 saying the record were already processed.

I am editing the stored proc to always insert a 1 flag to specific record so it would not be process.

The code work like this

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[personel]
        ([FirstName]
        ,[LastName]
        ,[IdNo]
        ,[ProcessedIndicator]
        ,[CreateDate]
Select AP.FirstNm
    ,AP.LastNm
    ,AP.Idno
    ,CASE 0
       WHEN AP.Locotion = '' AND AP.Position 0001 BETWEEN  AND 0005 
         THEN insert 1
       ELSE '0'
     END    
    ,GetDate()
from dbo.AllPersonel AS AP
```

Comment: What is your question? You could probably change `THEN insert 1` to just `THEN 1` if that is what you are asking about.

Answer (score 0):

Your `CASE` statement has several syntax (and spelling) problems. Try this:

```
CASE
    WHEN AP.Location = '' AND AP.Position BETWEEN 0001 AND 0005 THEN 1
    ELSE '0'
END
```

The `CASE` statement has two flavours:

```
CASE someExpression
    WHEN someValue THEN someResult
    ...
    ELSE someDefault
END
```

or

```
CASE
    WHEN someCondition THEN someResult
    ...
    ELSE someDefault
END
```

You were trying to mix the two forms.

Comment: Thanks i will give it a try and let you know

Comment: Case expression, not case statement.